# How can I update core without upgrading third-party modules?

Tags: composer

This is generally how I update Drupal core:

```
composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies
```

However, today when I do this, it is also upgrading the contrib modules.  I want to upgrade the core only.

Here is the first part of my composer.json:

```
{
"name": "drupal/drupal",
"description": "Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and applications.",
"type": "project",
"license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
"require": {
    "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^1.4",
    "drupal/entity_clone": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/features": "^3.8",
    "drupal/metatag": "^1.8",
    "drupal/webform": "^5.1",
    "drupal/config_installer": "^1.8",
    "drupal/entity_browser": "^2.1",
    "drupal/media_entity_browser": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/entity_embed": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/file_browser": "^1.1",
    "drupal/admin_menu_search": "^1.0",
    "drupal/backup_migrate": "^4.0",
    "drupal/block_field": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/contact_block": "^1.4",
    "drupal/contribute": "^5.0@beta",
    "drupal/ctools": "^3.2",
    "drupal/entity_reference_revisions": "^1.6",
    "drupal/facets": "^1.3",
    "drupal/field_group": "^3.0",
    "drupal/form_placeholder": "^1.0",
    "drupal/formblock": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/glazed_helper": "^1.3",
    "drupal/google_analytics": "^3.0",
    "drupal/honeypot": "^1.29",
    "drupal/imce": "^1.7",
    "drupal/insert_block": "1.x-dev",
    "drupal/linkit": "^4.3",
    "drupal/login_emailusername": "^1.1",
    "drupal/material_admin": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/menu_link_attributes": "^1.0",
    "drupal/minifyhtml": "^1.6",
    "drupal/paragraphs": "^1.6",
    "drupal/pathauto": "^1.4",
    "drupal/redirect": "^1.3",
    "drupal/require_login": "^2.0",
    "drupal/search_api": "^1.11",
    "drupal/simple_sitemap": "^3.0",
    "drupal/simplenews": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/tfa": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/token": "^1.5",
    "drupal/video_embed_field": "^2.0",
    "drupal/view_unpublished": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/viewport": "^1.1",
    "drupal/viewsreference": "^1.4",
    "drupal/workflow_state_config": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/xmlsitemap": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/allowed_formats": "^1.1",
    "drupal/asset_injector": "^2.4",
    "drupal/taxonomy_access_fix": "^2.6",
    "drupal/text_summary_options": "^1.0",
    "drupal/migrate_source_csv": "^2.2",
    "drupal/migrate_plus": "^4.1",
    "drupal/migrate_tools": "^4.1",
    "drupal/migrate_file": "^1.1",
    "drupal/entityqueue": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/module_missing_message_fixer": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/rules": "^3.0@alpha",
    "ckeditor/autogrow": "^4.8",
    "ckeditor/codemirror": "^1.17",
    "ckeditor/fakeobjects": "^4.8",
    "ckeditor/image": "^4.8",
    "ckeditor/link": "^4.8",
    "codemirror/codemirror": "^5.36",
    "jquery/geocomplete": "^1.7",
    "jquery/icheck": "^1.0",
    "jquery/image-picker": "^0.3.0",
    "jquery/inputmask": "^3.3",
    "jquery/intl-tel-input": "^12.1",
    "jquery/rateit": "^1.1",
    "jquery/select2": "^4.0",
    "jquery/timepicker": "^1.11",
    "jquery/toggles": "^4.0",
    "jquery/word-and-character-counter": "^2.5",
    "progress-tracker/progress-tracker": "^1.4",
    "signature_pad/signature_pad": "^2.3",
    "drupal/image_widget_crop": "^2.2",
    "drupal/crop": "^1.5",
    "drupal/better_exposed_filters": "^3.0@alpha",
    "drupal/block_visibility_groups_admin": "^1.3",
    "drupal/content_export_csv": "^3.0@beta",
    "drupal/contentimport": "^4.1",
    "drupal/event": "1.x-dev",
    "drupal/entity_reference_views_select": "^1.3",
    "drupal/imce_search_plugin": "^1.0",
    "drupal/inline_entity_form": "^1.0@RC",
    "drupal/job": "^3.0@alpha",
    "drupal/media_bulk_upload": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/memcache": "^2.0",
    "drupal/purge_ui": "^3.0@beta",
    "drupal/purge_processor_lateruntime": "^3.0@beta",
    "drupal/purge_tokens": "^3.0@beta",
    "drupal/twig_tweak": "^2.1",
    "drupal/views_bulk_operations": "^2.5",
    "drupal/block_visibility_groups": "^1.3",
    "drush/drush": "^9.5",
    "drupal/we_megamenu": "^1.5",
    "drupal/views_infinite_scroll": "^1.5",
    "drupal/embed": "^1.0",
    "drupal/dropzonejs": "^2.0@alpha",
    "drupal/purge": "^3.0@beta",
    "drupal/address": "^1.4",
    "drupal/purge_purger_http": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/smtp": "1.0-beta6",
    "drupal/content_sync": "^2.1",
    "drupal/console": "~1.0",
    "drupal/devel": "^2.0",
    "drupal/search_api_solr": "^1.2",
    "drupal/bootstrap": "^3.17",
    "drupal/captcha": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/core": "^8.9"
},
```

Comment: Is it the same when you do just `$ composer update drupal/core`? Can it be that you deleted your composer.lock file? Please also read [drupal/drupal deprecated](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies#deprecated-drupal-drupal). There is stated: *With drupal/drupal Drupal core cannot be updated with Composer, and updates are going to be extremely difficult. You can not apply Drupal core patches with cweagans/composer-patches. Avoid this solution.* You should switch to a different template instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, deleting composer.lock did not fix the problem.  The contrib modules still upgrade.  Does the page you link to suggest the docs are wrong at https://www.drupal.org/docs/updating-drupal/updating-drupal-core-via-composer -- I don't think so, initially.

Comment: Um, now I'm completely confused.  The database now says the contrib modules didn't upgrade, but git status suggests they did.  I suspect the database is right at this point, and your suggestion to remove composer.lock actually worked.  And I'm just confused about what I'm seeing in the git status.

Comment: The page I linked to suggests you use a different Composer template. Not `"name": "drupal/drupal"`. Instead refactor your composer.json to look like the one from the [drupal/recommended-project](https://github.com/drupal/recommended-project/blob/8.8.x/composer.json) template. Don't delete the lock file. Of course everything installs in a different version than in the lock file when you remove it.

Comment: It's actually not a difficult task. Just get the site up and running locally where you can break things without a problem. And then refactor your composer.json until everything (root, core, modules, themes) is there where it was before.

Comment: @leymannx was asking if you deleted the composer.lock file and that caused the issue you described. He wasn't saying that deleting that file is the way to fix the issue.

Comment: Also, Composer updates the files, but that is not sufficient to update a module. For that, Drupal needs to invoke its `hook_update_N()` implementations. Once Drupal does that, the database shows as installed the version Composer copied.

Comment: Yes, composer is a package manager. It does not interact with the database. Git shouldnt (really) be tracking the contrib directory either.